# Is there a Paizo official 18-20 or 20x4 bow?

Tags: pathfinder-1e

I am looking for an 18-20 bow or crossbow for my Magus 8 / Arcane Archer 10
Although I expect it to be x2, if it is x3, that would be phenomenal.

Alternatively a 20 x4 bow.

I have the feat to burn for it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As far as I can tell, there are no Pathfinder missile weapons with a crit range better than 19-20. Firearms do generally have a x4 crit multiplier though, if this helps - they are in [Ultimate Combat](http://paizo.com/pathfinderRPG/prd/ultimateCombat/combat/firearms.html), the Inner Sea World Guide, and Ultimate Equipment.

Update : there are some technological weapons in the [Technology Guide](http://paizo.com/pathfinderRPG/prd/technologyGuide/weapons.html) with an 18-20/x2, and 20/x4 critical ranges. They're still not bows, and are Exotic weapons to boot, AND have a basic cost measured in the tens of thousands...

Comment: There actually are ranged weapons with an 18-20/X2 or a 20/X4 critical code, but they are all firearms from the technology guide.  The Nuclear Resonator (18-20/X2), X-Laser (probably the best option, 20/X4), and Railgun (20/X4) are the weapons, if you're interested.  They aren't bows or crossbows though.