# Is there a ranged weapon with an 18-20 crit range?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, weapons

I have looked for a ranged weapon with an 18-20 critical threat range. So far I have only been able to find the [Crystal Chakram](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/equipment---final/weapons/weapon-descriptions/chakram-crystal) but obviously it is not a good option for a main weapon as it shatters after each hit.

Is there a ranged weapon, preferably a bow or crossbow, in Pathfinder that has a crit range of 18-20?

3rd party is accepted.

Related to [Is there a paizo official 18-20 or 20x4 bow](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/29423/is-there-a-paizo-official-18-20-or-20x4-bow) This question has a slightly broader range of including all ranged weapons and also not limited to official Paizo weapons.

Comment: Would you accept thrown weapons, or guns?

Comment: @Zibbobz bows and crossbows are preferred but thrown and guns are acceptable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The sniper rifle from the Thunderscape campaign setting (magi-tech steampunk setting) has an 18-20/x3 critical, ridiculous damage, not a terrible reload speed, and an added benefit for classes with precision damage that causes it to be moved up to "the only firearm in the setting that requires an Exotic Weapon Proficiency".

It's not quite the same, but the same setting also has the Crystal Bow, which is NOT made of crystal (exactly), has a 19-20/x3 critical, otherwise longbow-equivalent DPR, and a longer range increment than the sniper rifle.  For races or classes with Exotic Proficiencies to spare (which happens in that setting), a Crystal Bow makes an excellent main-weapon for someone who starts a fight with the sniper rifle.

Adding magic to these weapons just makes them that much better;  a spell storing scoped sniper rifle delivering scorching rays at the spell's max range makes my inner munchkin squeal with joy.

Comment: Thunderscape is the only pre-made setting I run, although I'm considering actually setting my next game in Golarion.  It has some nice stuff I like to port out, though;  the "folk magic" traits have very nicely flavored some of my other characters.  Thanks, @thedarkwanderer.

Answer (score 6):

First of all, if magic weapons are allowed I would strongly suggest getting a *throwing* melee weapon with a 18-20 crit multiplier.  Scimitars, Falchions, Kukri, Rhoka, and Elven Curve Blades are all example base weapons.  The best possible base is probably the monowhip (2d6 18-20/**X3** light weapon) from Paizo's Pathfinder Campaign Setting: Technology Guide, but adding the throwing quality  to whips, while RAW, is probably unallowed in most games.  A chainsaw (3d6 18-20/X2 two-handed weapon) is nearly as good and more likely to be accepted.

Assuming you want a non-magic ranged weapon with 18/20 crit, the technology guide also lists the Nuclear Resonator, which is an exotic two-handed firearm sporting a nice damage profile and an 18-20/X2 base multiplier.  It is a bit pricey, though, at 90K gp and has a ton of drawbacks, not least of which is its overly-impressive name, which is likely to make the unfamiliar reject it out of hand.  It could make a good primary weapon but you'd need a backup to deal with forcefields.

I don't play with 3pp and I don't know anyone who does, so I'm not qualified to answer with regards to items from such sources.  A kindly future editor or another answerer should add such suggestions.